# Laravel 5.8 many to many relation using custom column names for pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table, laravel-5.8

I have two tables `user_details` and `location` as below:

```
user_details
    user_id (INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)
    ......

location
    id (INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY)
    ......
```

These two tables are related to one another by many to may relationship. Now I am using a pivot table `location_user_details` as shown below

```
location_user_details
    id (INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY),
    user_id (INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES use_details.user_id)
    location_id (INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES location.id)
    type (VARCHAR)
```

The relation code for model `UserDetails` is as below:

```
class UserDetails extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    ........
    public function location(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Location::class, 'location_user_details', 'user_id', 'id')->withPivot('type');
    }
}
```

The relation code for model `Location` is as below:

```
class Location extends Model
{
    ......
    public function userDetails(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserDetails::class, 'location_user_details', 'id', 'user_id')->withPivot('type');
    }
}
```

Now in my controller, I am creating the relation after saving both `UserDetails` and `Location` object by the following code:

```
$userDetails->location()->attach($location->id, ['type'=>'HEADQUARTER']);
```

When the code reaches this line of execution, I get the following exception:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'location_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `location_user_details` (`id`, `type`, `user_id`) values (1, HEADQUARTER, 0))

I want to point out to two things that are happening.

1. The location field is not getting into the query to insert data.
2. The `user_id` value is `0` which should be greater than `0` as the data is getting inserted into the `user_details` table.

Now let me mention here that when I go to the database to look up for data in `location` and `user_details` table, I find all the data has been inserted.

Now my question is what has possible gone wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well at last I have found what went wrong. There is not much documentation on this topic. Actually it lies with the use of the function `belongsToMany`. The `belongsToMany`function takes up-to 7 parameters. Till now I could decode the first 4 parameters.

The first parameter takes the class of the related model.

The second parameter takes the name of the pivot table in the database.

The third parameter takes the name of the column in the pivot table that references the model on which `belongsToMany` is called.

The fourth parameter takes the name of the column in the pivot table that references the related model.

So as a result the code for function `location` in the model `UserDetails` would look like :

```
public function location(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Location::class, 'location_user_details', 'user_id', 'location_id')->withPivot('type');
}
```

And the code for function `userDetails` in the model `Location` would look like :

```
public function userDetails(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(UserDetails::class, 'location_user_details', 'location_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('type');
}
```

I hope this would be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in the variable **$location**, but it is not shown as you create it. Make sure it is a **Location Object**

Comment: @EricRF the `$location` stores a new instance of `Location` object. Then I save it using `$location->save()`. Now  this code is executed properly as I can find the data in the `locations` table in the database. Also look at the problem #2. The id of the object `UserDetails` is coming as `0`. How is it possible?

Comment: I think it's because you specify that the primary key in UserDetails is user_id

Comment: @EricRF But I have already declared `user_id` as primary key in the `UserDetails` model. Please see the code in in the question section above